# Buscar string en directorio, sub-directorios y archivos linux

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo este **string**: `MY_STRING`y tengo este **directorio**:

```
|root
|-MY_STRING      // <- directorio con MY_STRING por nombre
|--MY_FILE.txt   // <- archivo con MY_STRING escrito en el
|home
|-MY_STRING.txt  // <- archivo con MY_STRING por nombre
```

Quisiera poder buscar `MY_STRING`mediante un comando y que me devuelva algo como:

```
/root/MY_STRING
/root/MY_STRING/MY_FILE.txt
/home/MY_STRING.txt
```

De momento he intentado con comandos más o menos así:

```
grep -ril "MY_STRING" /
grep -rnw '/'-e "MY_STRING"
```

Pero estos solo me devuelven la ruta del archivo:

```
/root/MY_STRING/MY_FILE.txt
```

Comment: Nótese que `grep` te devolverá los archivos que _contienen_ este texto, no aquellos cuyo nombre sea este.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, parece que este es un caso en el que `ls -l $PWD/MY_STRING*` daría un resultado bastante bueno. Mejor que usar `find` o `grep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find <DIRECTORIO_INICIAL> [ OPCIONES ] -n <NOMBRE BUSCADO>`

En tu caso concreto, suponiendo que estas en el directorio /

```
find . -name MY_STRING
```

Si estas en otro directorio, y quieres buscar a partir del raiz

```
find / -name MY_STRING
```

Si necesitas *comodines*, tienes que escaparlos, para que la *shell* no haga de las suyas:

```
find / -name que_empiece_asi\*
```

Si quieres acortar el tiempo, y que no se meta en otros sistemas de archivos, tales como `/dev`, `/sys`, `/proc`, ...

```
find / -mount -name \*que_contenga_esto\*
```

Si quieres que un listado detallado

```
find / -mount -name \*yo_que_se\* -exec ls -l '{}' \;
```

La página del manual te mostrará todas las opciones: `man find`. Es un comando muy completo y útil.

**EDITO**

No había leído bien tu pregunta. Lo que quieres es que te muestre cualquier aparición de MY_STRING, sea en el nombre o en la ruta.

En ese caso, tienes que encadenar 2 comandos:

```
find / | fgrep TEXTO
```

`find` te muestra el contenido de todos los directorios.

`fgrep` te muestra solo las líneas que contengan los caracteres que indiques.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con el comando find

si no me equivoco seria asi:

```
find "my string"
```

Comment: Creo que esto sería más bien un comentario que una respuesta.